# Schur powers/functors of $GL_n$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

In Fulton Harris, p237 Section 15.5, it is said that all representations $S^\lambda V$ of $GL(V)$ were written down, and an exercise is given for this. I am wondering if (and where) this is written down in literature though, whether it is a result that proves the statement in the exercise, or a table, or something else.